# Flights: find lowest price flight combinations

Tags: c#, linq

A destination may have 2 connected flights, for example

For Frankfurt to Boston

Frankfurt-London (at 08:00-10:00, 14:00-18:00 etc.) with flight number fl1, fl2

London-Boston (at 10:00-12:00, 16:00-20:00 etc.) with flight number lb1, lb2

Each flight may have classes such as A, B  etc. (from cheap to expensive)

I have already Cartesian such as of all combinations:

fl1/A - lb1/A  (fl1 being flight number / A being class)
fl1/A - lb1/B
fl1/B - lb1/A
fl1/B - lb1/B
...
fl2/B - lb2/B

What should I present at end screen is lowest price flight for each destination combination:

fl1/A - lb1/A
fl1/A - lb2/A
fl2/A - lb1/A
fl2/A - lb2/A

How can I achieve this with linq query/queries?

What should I do find lowest priced flight for

---

I have Destination and Flight classes:

```
Class Destination 
{
    List<Flight> Flights
}
```

and

```
Class Flight{
    List<String> @Classes;   //such as A,B,C,D,E  
    String FlightId;       
}
```

So far I can have flatten list of flights with:

```
var flights = destination.SelectMany(d=>d.flights);
```

But I cannot figure out how to continue?

Note: I hope I did not make mistake while simplifying my real case

Here is what it looks like my case on html table structure:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if the way to arrive at your answer is clear, at least not to me. Are you just talking a sort by flight class?

Comment: Sorry for that, I am trying to make lowest fare of connected flights combinations from Cartesian

Comment: @octavioccl for the moment for simplicity let's keep it 2 connected flights. For the property Flight of Destination class, I think we could think it as `ConnectedFlight` only. As I mentioned in question, I tried make it simple version of real case..

Comment: Linq is quite slow, so I wouldn't recommend using it in algorithms such as this one with many possible records. Also, replace your classes array of strings with an array of enum values. Strings are longer to compare and you have update them everywhere in your code.

Comment: Also, do you have a price for each flight as class variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me is unclear yet, but if each destination has two connected flights

```
public class Destination
{
   public Flight Flight1 {get;set;}
   public Flight Flight2 {get;set;}
}
```

I would do something like this:

```
var comb =   (from dest in destinations
              from fc1 in dest.Fligth1.Classes.Select(s=>new {FlightId=dest.Flight1.FlightId, Class=s})
              from fc2 in dest.Fligth2.Classes.Select(s=>new {FlightId=dest.Flight2.FlightId, Class=s})
              select new {fc1, fc2}).OrderBy(e=>e.fc1.Class).ThenBy(e=>fc2.Class);
```

If you want to keet your list of Flights in `Destination`, I guess you can use the indexer of List:

```
var comb =   (from dest in destinations
              from fc1 in dest.Flights[0].Classes.Select(s=>new {FlightId=dest.Flights[0].FlightId, Class=s})
              from fc2 in dest.Flights[1].Classes.Select(s=>new {FlightId=dest.Flights[1].FlightId, Class=s})
              select new {fc1, fc2}).OrderBy(e=>e.fc1.Class).ThenBy(e=>e.fc2.Class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me check it

Comment: Hi @asdf_enel_hak, at the end did you try with one of my solutions?

Comment: I am a bit lost at these times, I'll have a look. Let me accept it

Comment: No worries, if you need any additional help, just let me know