# How to join nth list

Tags: c#, linq, join

First of all thanks for patience to read such long question. This is the shortest version, I can produce so far.

This question is sub question of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36778570/492258). Once I clarify it, I will update it and ask to reopen then I can answer it

My question is is there practical way of `nth` combination of below code.

I have itinerary composed connected flights whose count 1,2 .. n
Each flight may have classes such  A, B, C ...

---

I am combining each flight with the same class

Here is my code which produces combinations:

```
//combination of ONE flightSegments
var firstFlightSegments = flightSegments.Where(s => s.Count == 1).ToList();

var originDestination = 
    (from firstFlightSegment in firstFlightSegments
    select
        new originDestination {
            pnr = Utils.GeneratePnr(),
            flightSegments = new List<FlightSegment>{firstFlightSegment}
        }
    )
```

---

```
//combinations of TWO flightSegments
var firstFlightSegments = flightSegments.Where(s => s.Count == 1).ToList();
var secondSecondSegments = flightSegments.Where(s => s.Count == 2).ToList();

var originDestination = 
    (from firstFlightSegment in firstFlightSegments
        join secondFlightSegment in secondSecondSegments
            on firstFlightSegments.flightClass equals secondSegment.flightClass
    select
        new originDestination {
            pnr = Utils.GeneratePnr(),
            flightSegments = new List<FlightSegment>{firstFlightSegment, secondFlightSegment}
        }
    )
```

---

```
//combinations of THREE flightSegments
var firstFlightSegments = flightSegments.Where(s => s.Count == 1).ToList();
var secondSecondSegments = flightSegments.Where(s => s.Count == 2).ToList();
var thirdFlightSegments = flightSegments.Where(s => s.Count == 3).ToList();

var originDestination = 
    (from firstFlightSegment in firstFlightSegments
        join secondFlightSegment in secondSecondSegments
            on firstFlightSegments.flightClass equals secondSegment.flightClass
                join thirdFlightSegment in thirdFlightSegments 
                    on secondSegment.flightClass equals thirdFlightSegment.flightClass       

    select
        new originDestination {
            pnr = Utils.GeneratePnr(),
            flightSegments = new List<FlightSegment>{firstFlightSegment, secondFlightSegment, thirdFlightSegment}
        }
```

---

```
//HOW TO DO combinations of N flightSegments

???
```

---

---

**EDIT**
After @Rhumborl answer which works fine according to upper side, I need to add this code to reflect that I need and additional field `MyIndex` that I will do group by on it

```
  var originDestination =   
        (from firstFlightSegment in firstFlightSegments
            join secondFlightSegment in secondSecondSegments
                on firstFlightSegments.flightClass equals secondSegment.flightClass
        select
            new originDestination {
                pnr = Utils.GeneratePnr(),
                myIndex = firstFlightSegment.FligthNumber + secondFlightSegment.FligthNumber
                flightSegments = new List<FlightSegment>{firstFlightSegment, secondFlightSegment}
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you want to get all the flight segments for a flight class and return them as a list in order of their count?

A simple [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx) will do it:

```
var flights = fightSegments
    .GroupBy(fs => fs.flightClass)  // get all steps for each flight together
    .Select(fc =>
        new originDestination {
            //flightClass = fc.Key, // if you need this
            pnr = Utils.GeneratePnr(),
            flightSegments = fc         // fc is the list of steps
                .OrderBy(s => s.Count)  // make sure it is in order
                .ToList()
        }
    )
```

If you want only flights with at least n steps, then you need to do a little more work to add an extra where clause in:

```
var flights = fightSegments
    .GroupBy(fs => fs.flightClass)
    .Where(fcg => fcg.Count() >= n) // make sure flight has n+ steps
    .Select(fc =>
        new originDestination {
            //flightClass = fc.Key, // if you need this
            pnr = Utils.GeneratePnr(),
            flightSegments = fc
                .OrderBy(s => s.Count)
                .ToList()
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer, please see edit, could add more details if it is possible